# Add file to resources in pom packaged parent project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

I have a parent project which contains multiple other projects.
The parent pom is declared as:

```
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <modules>
        <module>child1</module>
        <module>child2</module>
        ...
    </modules>
```

So my question is there any way to add a file into this parent pom project resources so all of the child projects will have this file in their resources?

```
- parent folder
- - child1 folder
- - child2 folder
- - pom.xml
- - settings.xml
...
```

The file is logging settings file, I think adding it to the parent resources might solve the problem of necessity of the copy of this file in the child projects.

Comment: What do you mean by `logging settings file`? Having something in resources means on the classpath...so make a separate child module put the appropriate file into it's resources directory `src/main/resources` and define a dependency to that module...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I mean exactly that, and yes, I can do it, but in this case will the file be visible in the other projects if I add it as the dependency?

Comment: Something like `log4j.properties`.. And yes of course it will be visible.. what is the problem? Apart from that why do you have a `settings.xml` in your project?